# New potential vulnerability in Laravel logout

Tags: laravel

there is a strange problem which might be a not discovered issue in Laravel security, it goes like this: while I submit an ajax form to update or insert to the database (a lot of data that takes too much time) and I logout from another tab in the middle of it, the request will still succeed without an issue! and more importantly after that my browser acts as if I did not logout at all ! am I going crazy or do we have a problem ?

```
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
```

Comment: I would suggest reaching out to the project/repo owner for things like issue reports. Unfortunately this is off-topic here.

Comment: Are you really expecting your database engine to verify authentication, and in a middle of a query?

Comment: This is not a problem. You were authenticated when you made the request. If for some reason it's important for your application not to do this, you should check the session again *after* the long-running task and revert the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most people this is not a security vulnerability.

This happens because Laravel checks authentication at middlewares, that runs BEFORE calling the controller method. So at the time your request starts, you're still authenticated.

Comment: thanks, the problem is that when the response finishes, the browser acts like it did not logout at all! it only happens while a i logout from another tab when a request  is running

Comment: Browser don't know about authentication. It just sends the cookie, if fhe request started before the logout response the browser will still send the cookie to the server. The server also just check the cookie validity at the begining of the request. If you start a request that takes 1h to finish then logout, the request will still be valid.